# Problem setting 301 redirection statements in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I'm having some trouble setting up a htaccess file. Currently I have 15 domains serving their own website. Now moving this to a single website and domain, I want to serve a htaccess with 301 rules for the old urls. The destination url depends on the domainname of the old url..

E.g.

`http://www.previouswebsiteinspanish.com/contacto` should be permanently rewritten to `http://www.newcentralwebsite.eu/es/contact`

I understand that I have to use the RewriteCond but I'm not familiar enough with it to get it working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?previouswebsiteinspanish/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/contacto$ /$1/contact [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current condition is that the rule will be executed under the condition that the referring page is not on the old domain. That's most likely not what you want to do. :)

You want to check the %{HTTP_HOST} parameter, which contains only the hostname part of the currently requested URL.

Assuming you want to redirect *everything* on the old domain to the `es` subfolder, this rule will do it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?previouswebsiteinspanish.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newcentralwebsite.eu/es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then you'll have to add similar rules for each old domain.

Comment: OP wrote he wants to redirect contacto to contact - so (.*) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

From your example the rule I wrote is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?previouswebsiteinspanish\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contacto$ http://www.newcentralwebsite.eu/es/contact [R=301,L]
```

Add such rules to your `.htaccess`. 
You have to write such rules for each domain.

In above case you have change in url too, so you may have to handle such special cases too.

Comment: You should escape . in RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?previouswebsiteinspanish\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contacto$ http://www.newcentralwebsite.eu/es/contact [R=301,L]
```

You need to check HTTP_HOST which is the hostname of the requested site.